# How do I determine whether Growl is running using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, growl

I the past, in order to determine whether the Growl helper is running on macOS, [I've used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11150307/656912)

```
tell application "System Events"
    set isRunning to (count of (every process whose bundle identifier is "com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp")) > 0
end tell
```

But recently, both this and an alternative thats been suggested

```
tell application "System Events" to set isRunning to exists (processes where name is "com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp")
```

just run forever. This seems to happen (only) when it (or more precisely the app "Hardware Growler" is not running), but is still clearly not the desired outcome.

How do I determine whether Growl is running using AppleScript?

Answer (score -1):

While I was not able to identify a process name that hints at GrowlHelper running in the background (Growl 2.13, Mac App Store version), I found an alternative solution.

In fact Growl 2.13 may not even need to use GrowlHelperApp itself to launch on user login.

---

### Check whether Growl is set to launch on login

In Terminal type

```
defaults read ~/Library/Containers/com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp/Data/Library/Preferences/com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp.plist ShouldStartGrowlAtLogin
```

This will output a value of 1 (true) or 0 (false). This file is modified every time you toggle the switch in Growl's preferences.